# Determine if a parameter/variable  is a ("is_a?") lambda?

Tags: ruby, lambda

How to check if a given parameter is a lambda?

```
def method(parameter)
  if ???
      puts "We got lambda"
      parameter.call
  else
      puts "I did not get a block"
  end
end


method(lambda { 1 })
method(1)
```

Answer (score 43):

A block is *not* a lambda. To see if there is a block use [`block_given?`](http://apidock.com/ruby/Kernel/block_given%3F).

In any case, I would use "responds to call" *if and only if* I really needed this construct, which I would try to avoid. (Define the contract and make the *caller* responsible for invoking it correctly!)

```
 (lambda {1}).respond_to? :call # => true
 (1).respond_to? :call          # => false
```

I believe this form of *structural (aka duck) typing* is more inline with Ruby than *nominative typing* with "is a" relationships.

To see what "is a" relationships might hold (for future playing in a sandbox):

```
 RUBY_VERSION           # => 1.9.2
 (lambda {}).class      # => Proc
 (Proc.new {}).class    # => Proc
 def x (&p); p; end     # note this "lifts" the block to a Proc
 (x {}).class           # => Proc
```

Happy coding.

Comment: Very cool that there is a `respond_to?` method. Makes these sorts of things a lot easier.

Answer (score 4):

Actually you can check if variable `is_a?` a `Proc`

```
x = (lambda {})
x.is_a?(Proc) # true
```